# Understanding basic variable concepts

Tags: javascript, language-concepts

I'm having difficulties understanding the swapping of variables. There are many helpful threads explaining how to actually do it, but I am having difficulties understanding it. The example I'm talking about is:

```
var a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = a;
a = b;
b = c;
```

In my (very basic) understanding I read that in plain english as: the variable **c** per declaration holds whatever the variable **a** is pointing at. Since we assign **a = b** after the declaration, shouldn't the next assignment make **b** hold the value 2 (because **c** is pointing at **a** which we just assigned to **b**)?

Comment: The variable `c` holds the same value that `a` is holding.  These are not references.  P.S. `b` and `c` are being declared *without* `var`.  You want to have `var a = 1, b = 2, c = a;`.  Notice the commas.

Comment: Thanks, had i paid more attention I should have seen that with the declaration. I guess its a bit of a pitfall that JS accepts it nonetheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript is [call/assign by **value**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) (more specifically, [call/assign by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)) I.e. when you assign a variable to another variable, the value of the variable is copied. Assigning a new value to a variable **never** changes the value of another variable. There is no implicit link between them.

A bit more visual: Assuming that `b` holds the value `v`, then after `a = b`, we have

```
b -> v
a -> v
```

You seem to think that we have `a -> b -> v` instead, which is **not** the case.

In your example:

```
c = a; // c now holds the value 1
a = b; // a now holds the value 2
b = c; // b now holds the value 1
```

Comment: If it is a simple type, not objects (and arrays).

Comment: No, it applies to every type. In case of objects, the value if a reference.

Comment: For complex objects it holds a reference, for simple ones it holds the actual value itself. I don't care how you call it (claiming the reference is a "value"), your explanation for a newbie is BAD if you do that. They will believe the object is the value and it is (deep) copied.

Comment: @Mörre - javascript doesn't pass by reference, it's always pass by value, but for complex objects, the value holds a "copy of a reference".

Comment: @Mörre: A reference to the *object*, not to the memory location of the *variable*. References are also copied.

Comment: I have no idea what stuff you now come up with to still have yet another response??? And by the way, a reference is a pointer to a location in memory.

Comment: @Mörre: I recommend to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy and learn about the difference between *pass by value* and *pass by reference*.

Comment: Leaving out that little difference I mention is a BAD explanation esp. for newbies, end of story. I think you have no business telling me anything about what I should read, I seem to have a better grasp than you.

Comment: @Mörre: What I explained in my answer holds true for every value type.

Comment: @Mörre - But there is no passing references in javascript, saying there is would be even more wrong, it's all pass by value.

Comment: Only that you failed to mention the difference between passing of simple values and complex ones.

Comment: @adeneo If you declare a reference a value. But a reference is.. a reference! Hurra, what a surprise!

Comment: @Mörre: And what's the difference? Are you telling me that in case of an object, e.g. `var a = {}; b = a; a = {foo: 42};`, `b` suddenly refers to `{foo: 42}` as well?

Comment: No (filler for minimum character requirement).

Comment: @Mörre: Now that I saw the edit to your second comment I see what you mean. However, I also think that explaining how objects work in the JS is out of the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68236/discussion-on-answer-by-felix-kling-understanding-basic-variable-concepts).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So it was a misconception after all.

Answer (score 1):

No, in JavaScript assigning the value of one variable to another assigns a *copy* of the value. Thus after

```
c = a;
```

the variable "c" has a copy of the value that's in "a".  The subsequent assignment of a copy of the value of variable "b" to "a" has no effect on the value of "c".

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator *copies the value* of the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side. It does not create a reference to a variable.

When the statement `c = a` runs, the value of `a` is still `1`, so the value of `c` becomes `1`.

You do not change the value of `c` anywhere else in the code, so when you reach `b = c`, the value is still `1`.